# PHP execute sed shell command

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

Im trying to execute a sed shell command through PHP to change some string in a file.
The file is located at /etc/text.txt and I try to modify some text inside that file using following code :

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/etc/');
$cmd = "sed -i 's/footext/newtext/g' text.txt";
exec($cmd);
chdir($old_path);
```

But the text 'footext' at text.txt doesn't change.

Please help me solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Seems like your `www-data` or whatever user is doesn't have permissions to write in that directory. Quote: _If the Apache user (www-data) can write or modify /etc all the system is compromised._

Comment: To get access from within your php script, you should change the group (see chown) of the file to the same group apache/php is operating and give proper group permissions via chmod. For security sakes, apache only should have access to that only file in /etc.

Comment: The missing single quote that should close the regexp is a typo?

Comment: the single quote just a typo, I was add it.
user / group of the php script is kurnia kurnia and the user/group for the text.txt is vmail/exim.
any idea or reference to give the script access to that text.txt?
Thanks

Comment: I would absolutely move the file somewhere else to process it. Your webserver should not be allowed to access such a system sensitive directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd like to re-iterate the inherent dangers of allowing your (public) web-server to change system files. Doing this *will* lead to an attacker compromising your system, it's only a question of how much time it takes.

That said, there are a couple of issues with your code. The first of which is the reliance upon external third party (shell) commands, for something that could, and should, be done in pure PHP instead.
Editing text is one of PHP's main strengths, after all, and the code would be quite simple. As an example...

```
if (!$content = file_get_contents ($filename)) {
    // Handle errors opening/reading the file here.
}

// Assuming case-sensitive search and replace here, as per the `sed` used.
$content = str_replace ("old text", "new text", $content);

if (!file_put_contents ($filename, $content)) {
    // Handle errors with writing to the file here.
}
```

The main benefit of this is that you don't need to rely upon unrelated third party programs to be present (even though `sed` is quite ubiquitous). Which makes the code is a lot easier to understand, self-contained, and thus platform agnostic (to the fullest extent possible).

AS for why your code doesn't work, I too suspect that this has something to do with file permissions. As noted in the comments, the `www-data` user does not have permission to write to the `/etc/` folder by default. So in order to enable it to edit a file there, you first need to create the file with a root-enabled user, and then change the ownership to `www-data`.
However, do *not* under any circumstances do this to already existing files in this folder. The potential for unintended, and catastrophic, side effects is just too huge!

If you absolutely need to have a PHP script modify the system file, write a shell-script and invoke it via `crontab` or something similar. *After* you've made 100% sure that the input is 100% safe from abuse. (IE: Printable characters only, preferably ASCII.)